# 2-D Collision crash course

Tags: java, android, collision-detection

Can anyone give me a reference to sites, blogs, articles, or post themselves a crash course or easy help guide in 2-D collision detection for Android? I looked at collision code from an online tutorial but they didn't explain the collision part of the code - just the part of implementing sprites. I am not using OpenGL, I am using Canvas for my game. I have searched around but I keep finding stuff for OpenGL or C++ but I am using Java. Code examples that are explained would be highly appreciated. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: I'm sure the pun was intended.

Comment: 2-d or 3-d collision? Not sure if that makes a huge difference; just asking in case it does.

Comment: You can look at this other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183714/collision-detection-and-collision-response) (shown on the right side of this page).

Comment: Thanks, never really paid attention to that side.

Comment: @Cephron the 3D collision engine are more complex to put in place, take 2 squares you need to compare 8 points, 2 cubes you need to compare 16 points, I studied these algorithms and trust me adding that extra dimension does tests^2 lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

colliding rectangles is easiest (actually circles are but with sprites your not using those)

for 2 rectangles to collide/overlap some space needs to be shared

```
public class Sprite{
    private int left,right;//bounding box left<right and top>bottom
    private int top,bottom;

    public final boolean collidesWith(Sprite other){
        if(this.left>other.right || other.left>other.right)return false;
        if(this.bottom>other.top || other.bottom>other.top)return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

for getting which ones collide you can sweep over the entire board and check all the overlap in one dimension

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example. So is the this statement the other or the sprite class and the other is an object. I refer the other in the argument just in case it sounds confusing.

Comment: @manji both `this` and `other` are objects of the type `Sprite` (which I put in as a stub class but you should put it in the root of the hierarchy of all classes representing a sprite)

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can have a look at

http://www.jbox2d.org/

this website give you some perfomance comparaison :

http://www.4feets.com/2009/03/2d-physics-on-android-using-box2d/

(if you pick a engine you can then just go "engine tutorial" to find all the source code you need

otherwise you can write your own (depending on how complex are the physics you want)

---

but I will point out that using the canvas to draw real time physics is crazy slow, I started off doing it because I was testing engines but you will never get a good frame rate.

so unless you need physics just for a very small reason I would suggest you switch to opengl

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure I do though. It is a shooter like game where the bullet hits the target and the target is destroyed. Nothing special happens when he is destroyed.

Comment: its not a question of something special happens, the draw of a canvas is too slow to do real time physics, you have to think that the canvas is optimized to draw something once in a while so. you have to think that your app has to handle touch event + calculate the physics + draw your scene, if you stay with Canvas your app will most likely not have smooth animations. I'm just giving you the heads up since I did the same.

Comment: if you have something running with Canvas and that it is minimalisitc then maybe (I reread you description and I think you don't need a physics engine for what your doing so you might be better of wirtting your own collision algorithms and staying with Canvas)